# how can i extract the values saved in the for?...this is my code. but it does not work

Tags: javascript

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table"),
  sumVal = 0;

var aux = '';

function prueba() {
  for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    var sumVal = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    aux = sumVal;
    console.log(sumVal);

  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `<table>`? What value are you expecting to get? You're reassigning a new value to the `aux` variable on each iteration of the loop; without your "*[mcve]*" code we really can't offer any further, or useful, help.

Comment: Please also add some more textual context for your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that every iteration of the loop, you are overwriting the value of your `aux` variable.  You need to change `aux` to an array so that you can add to it.  Here is a
[Javascript Array tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) that might be able to help you understand.

```
var aux = [];//the array 

function prueba(){
  for(var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++){   
    var sumVal = parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);
    aux.push(sumVal);//add the value to the end of the array
  }
}
prueba();
console.log(aux);//console.log the contents of the array
```